# Json Array Issue in Code-igniter MySql

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter

Below is my code :

```
    $this->db->select("city_id,loc_id,loc_name");
    $this->db->from("locations");
    $this->db->group_by("city_id");
    $this->db->order_by("city_id", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return json_encode($query->result_array());
```

It give me result as below:

```
[{"city_id":"1","loc_id":"17","loc_name":"Al Barsha"} {"city_id":"2","loc_id":"12","loc_name":"testt"}]
```

But i want to get like

```
{"1":{"17":"Al Barsg","35":"XYZ"},"2":{"123":"ABC","44":"OtherName"}}
```

I do not understand how to do it?

Comment: You should create string for it!

Comment: How to create string as there is city id. Do i need to create join query with city table?

Comment: if you dont want city_id remove it from your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return json_encode(array($query->result_array());
```

Output

```
["0":{"city_id":"1","loc_id":"17","loc_name":"Al Barsha"}...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply BUT i need only loc_id and loc_name like ["0":{"17":"Al Barsha"......} , "1":{"18":"another"} where 0 & 1 are city_ids

Comment: its not feasible. loop through this. Cz if you want id of element you cant get it. use this way

Comment: So you mean,what i want is not possible?

Comment: just assume you want delete a record. so that you use the id. But in your case it cant done.